# Place and Route, what causes this?

Tags: fpga

I couldn't find a forum on this subject about what causes this.
What causes Place and Route and how do you resolve this issue? I know that its when timing isn't correct, but what causes this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather general - it would make it a great deal easier helping you if you can narrow it down. For example giving information about the used language, tool chain, etc. would help to put everything into a context. However, I will try to answer by assuming some things:

-Implied question: what is Place and Route

"Place and Route" is one step of the full process. It typically takes place after a formerly descript logic is translated into physically existing logic blocks present on a specified chip. Typically multiple instances of the same block exists on a chip. During the "Place and Route" step an algorithm tries to select the instances and connect them via the existing matrix in such way that the result delays between the "components" are less than the maximum allowed timing. For example if a memory block is physically located on the left side of an FPGA the algorithm will try to use logic cells next to it to "realize processing logic" as patching the data through to logic cells on the opposit side would increase delays and consume more "pathways".

-What causes "Place and Route Errors"

If you get "Place and Route Errors" it typically means that the algorithm could not find a combination or layout where the delays for the requested design stay below the required time limits or really fit the design into the given number of components/connections. The time limits are deducted from the specified frequencies. Lower frequencies imply less stringent timing conditions.

-How to resolve "Place and Route Errors"

This strongly depends on the design. Sometimes it can be attributed to poor (clock) specifications or clock domain crossing of signals or too long "pipelines" or too little resources (i.e. left over logic cells) for the given design. Depending on the used tools you can revive a log or overview which states what part of your design might be the main reason for the violation.

A nice example for a too long pipeline is the the attempt to sum all bit of an input vector with length N. If simpled implemented by a generated loop the "add" logics will be chained in a row resulting in a delay of approximately N * delay_between_logic_cells. One solution is to split the vector into to parts, clock the resulting part sums into two intermediate buffers and output the sum of those two clocked buffers. This effectively reduce the overall delay to roughly (N / 2 + 1) * delay_between_logic_cells.

However, this is merely a poor introduction into this topic and a quick internet search will yield much more precise and detailed information about those topics.